# Cloud of Java objects

Tags: java

I'm wondering whether there's an existing framework or technology concept for the following project.

I have a simulation that involves a few hundred thousand Java objects. Each has a unique ID and state, and must be able to send message objects to each other. I'd like to load balance and hot-swap over multiple servers, with a system that automatically optimizes the object distribution across the servers based on their frequency of message passing (objects that talk to each other the most are moved to the same server, groups of talkers are moved to separate servers). Objects must be able to get a periodic timeslice even if nobody is connected, so the simulation is always running.

Basically, just a pile of running Java objects that are dumped onto a dynamic server farm, that automagically optimize their location on the farm and can spawn and communicate with the other objects trivially.

Comment: I guess you may need to rewrite load balancer with your custom requirement (or) a plugin for existing load balancer (if you have any). Another possibility I see is, Thread Executor pool with priorities setup.

Comment: http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like [Akka](http://akka.io/) and [Killim](http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim/) can handle the communication side of things.

Grouping "mutual talkers", not so sure--that's likely an area of ongoing research across actor frameworks and languages. There are lots of papers discussing things like this, and I'm sure implementations are available, but I can't speak to their robustness (or location, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Google's Big Table does elastic transparent management of itself. You can add and remove machines and it will expand onto them automatically.

Clustering won't be easy because object don't (in real life) talk only to the same objects. (Facebook tried clustering users and has concluded that it's no possible for them to do that)

To answer your question, I don't think there is any such framework.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.softwarematters.org/jini-intro.html for a discussion of technologies in this space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at Storm.

> Distributed RPC: Distributed RPC is perhaps the most unexpected and
>   most compelling use case for Storm. There are a lot of queries that
>   are both hard to precompute and too intense to compute on the fly on a
>   single machine. Traditionally, you have to do an approximation of some
>   sort to lower the cost of a query like this. Storm gives the
>   capability to parallelize an intense query so that you can compute it
>   in realtime.

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm

http://tech.backtype.com/preview-of-storm-the-hadoop-of-realtime-proce